# Javascript assign functions returned array to another array with all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

In $(document).ready I am making in ajax request in a function, which returns json data which I add to an array. I am returning the array from that function but when I try to assign whats returned to another array my alert doesn't show an array full of values.

```
 function retrieveGroupNames() {
        var rows = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("LookUpGroupName", "UserManager")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    rows[i] = {
                        data: data[i],
                        value: data[i].group,
                        result: data[i].group
                    }
//                    alert(data[i].group);
                    //                    alert(data[1].group);
                } // end of for loop
                //                alert(rows[1].value);


            } // end of success
        });   // end of ajax
//        alert(rows); data here
        return rows;

    } // end of function

$(document).ready(function () {
        chkSelection();
        var rows = [];
        rows = retrieveGroupNames();
        alert(rows);
    });
```

Some help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

AJAX is asynchronous. You can't return stuff that relies on the request being finished. You need to use a callback instead:

```
function retrieveGroupNames(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("LookUpGroupName", "UserManager")',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            var rows = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                rows[i] = {
                    data: data[i],
                    value: data[i].group,
                    result: data[i].group
                }
            }
            callback(rows);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    chkSelection();
    retrieveGroupNames(function(rows) {
        alert(rows);
    });
});
```

Comment: Good to see the callback function passed as parameter to a function and getting executed after ajax. I was struggled before, now got an idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The other option other than the callback provided in ThiefMaster's answer is to use [`$.Deferred` objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Using deferreds gives you control over when and what should happen during asynchronous processing, such as ajax calls.

```
function retrieveGroupNames() {
    // create a deferred object
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data) {
            var rows = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                rows[i] = {
                    data: data[i],
                    value: data[i].group,
                    result: data[i].group
                }
            }
            // resolve the deferred and pass the rows as data
            deferred.resolve(rows);
        }
    });

    // return a promise
    return deferred.promise();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // use the when...then syntax to consume the deferred function
    $.when(retrieveGroupNames()).then(function (rows) {
        // do whatever you want with rows 
    });
});
```

Also note that `$.ajax` already returns a promise itself, so you could just say `return $.ajax({...});` in your `retrieveGroupNames` function.

Comment: Indeed, that's also a nice idea. I actually thought about adding it when asnwering the question but then decided that I'm too lazy :P - Anyway, you don't need the `$.when()` - just `retrieveGroupNames().then(..)` should do the job, too.